# How to loop over checked boxes and add to array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am needing to loop over all of the checked check boxes of a specific name and add the values of that row to an array.  My final array needs to look like this:

```
stmtData = {
    sections: [
        { sectionCode: "AA", sectionName: "AA Test", amount: "33" },
        { sectionCode: "BB", sectionName: "BB Test", amount: "55" }
    ]
};
```

Looping over the checkboxes is the easy part:

```
var stmtData = [];
$.each($("input:checkbox[name='sectionElection']:checked"), function () {
    // create sections array here

});
```

I'm getting the data like this, but there may be a better way?

```
stmtData["sectionCode"] = $(this).val();
stmtData["sectionName"] = $("#sectionElectionLbl_" + $(this).val()).text();
stmtData["amount"] = $("#sectionCost_" + $(this).val()).text();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could improve it using map instead of each, bit rusty on jQuery but something like?

```
var stmtData = {}
stmtData.section = $("input:checkbox[name='sectionElection']:checked")
.map(function() {

  var val = $(this).val();
  var text = val.text();
  return {
        sectionCode: val,
        sectionName = $("#sectionElectionLbl_" + text,
        amount: text
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I knew I had to use push somehow, figured it out and this works just fine.

```
var stmtData = [];
$.each($("input:checkbox[name='sectionElection']:checked"), function () {
    // create sections array here
    stmtData.push({
        sectionCode: $(this).val(),
        sectionName: $("#sectionElectionLbl_" + $(this).val()).text(),
        amount: $("#sectionCost_" + $(this).val()).text()
    });
});
```